# Compose component inside xml is not redrawn when fragments are being replaced

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have added a compose component in a custom view XML which is added from a fragment, where the project is using a navigation graph library. But when I navigate from this fragment and come back the UI(XML) will be restored except the composed component inside it. It looks like the entire UI is getting redrawn without the compose component when the fragments are being replaced.

compose component inside XML

```
    ...
                    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
                    android:id="@+id/expando_link_compose"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subheading"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/heading"
                    />
    ...
```

and setting up here

```
  findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.expando_link_compose).apply {
      visibility = VISIBLE
  setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                AppTheme {
                    SurfaceView(....)
                }
            }
        }
```

I have checked with the layout inspector but Compose component is shown in both scenarios,  also tried different ViewCompositionStrategy

Comment: my guess goes for the fact that it's `wrap_content` size, is there a way to give it something more concrete? Or `0dp` or `constrainedWidth="true"` etc

Comment: tried with fixed width and height but no luck..